# Session Auth in Django-Rest-Framwork, Is this really what I have to do to make is CSRF safe?

Tags: authentication, session, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

First off, this code works, it just doesn't feel as clean as it should be for something so simple.

Background:
I'm trying to make a custom login API endpoint in DRF that will be consumed by the React Frontend.  It seems you have to manually force a csrf to be sent in DRF so that's what I have done.

I didn't want to send over a Django Form because it didn't seem RESTful, but this is the only method I could find to avoid that.  Please let me know if this is clean code.

Serializers.py

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model # If used custom user model

UserModel = get_user_model()


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = UserModel.objects.create_user(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            password=validated_data['password'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
        )

        return user

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        # Tuple of serialized model fields (see link [2])
        fields = ( "id", "username", 'email', "password", )
```

View.py

```py
from rest_framework import permissions

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model # If used custom user model
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

from .serializers import UserSerializer

from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie, csrf_protect


class CreateUserView(APIView):
    model = get_user_model()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny # Or anon users can't register
    ]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie)
    def get(self, request, format = None):
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    @method_decorator(csrf_protect)
    def post(self,request, format = None):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.create(serializer.validated_data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

CSRF is enabled by Django, not DRF. And as specified, CSRF protections only kick in when logged in.

Login and registration actions does not need to be CSRF protected (as the password data is needed, and cannot be guessed, in a CSRF attack scenario) by the attacker.

Also per Django spec, GET actions/views are not protected by CSRF. However, GET actions should not change the state of your application. If it's not the case, and you're able to implemant the CSRF protection on your front (which is possible for REST app, but not with default Django app), you can manually protect it with your decorator.

This is mainly not a DRF issue but a Django issue.

Comment: I think you're right about most things, however this seems to contradict your second paragraph https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/?fbclid=IwAR3MsatN4y3bn4EvmFNqOBD5ua8N3OvgbfTUzNCOLAk_zVha7WBQZsomdRY#sessionauthentication , if I'm not mistaken

Comment: I get what you're 3rd paragraph says (mostly) but I'm not sure how it relates, if you could draw the parallel or provide an example of how to do CSRF on the front end, that would be much appreciated :)